# WSO2 API Manager: deploy tiers.xml

Tags: deployment, wso2, wso2-api-manager, throttling

How can I deploy my tiers.xml file into the WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 via command line or via json or webservices? Is this possible? Currently I can do this via the carbon console. 
I need this requirement while I am provisioning my server park via puppet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tiers.xml  is stored in the registry, you can update tiers.xml via the Registry apis. Please refer following links [[1](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance452/Registry+API)](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance452/Registry+API) and  [[2](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance452/Adding+a+Resource+with+API)](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance452/Adding+a+Resource+with+API) for more information on Registry APIs and how to put/get values from the registry.